# React login form loop isn't re-rendering DOM

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to make a login component and I think my issue is with React not re-rendering the DOM in my browser but I'm not sure why

If I leave the password field blank when I press the main 'Login' button in my form it will render the alert / warning message .. I can then click this message to dismiss it which is exactly what I want

If I were to repeat the process I would expect the message to be re-rendered and the DOM element reintroduced, however this is not the case - I can see that the loop is being run, I am getting all of the console logs with the correct values, however the loop does not seem to run the 'return' part of my if statement on the second try (in the code below I've added 'this return doesn't re-render' to the console log before that return) - here's my code

Apologies for the large code snippet but I felt it was all relevant for this question

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: "",
            password: "",
            errors: [],
        };
    this.onLoginClick = this.onLoginClick.bind(this);
}

onLoginClick() {
    const username = this.state.email.trim();
    const password = this.state.password.trim();
    let errors = [];

    console.log("Login press")

    if (!EMAIL_REGEX.test(username)) {
        errors.push(error_user);
        console.log("Username error")
    }

    if (password === "") {
        errors.push(error_pass);
        console.log("Password is blank")
    }

    if (errors.length === 0) {
        this.props.onLoginClick(username, password);
    if (this.props.loginStatus === login_f) {
        errors.push(error_cred);
    }
}

this.setState({
    errors: errors,
});

console.log("Here are the errors", errors)
}

handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
};
handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
};
clearAlertsHandler() {
    console.log("Clear alerts")
    document.getElementById("misMatch").remove()
}

render() {
    let updatedErrors = [...this.state.errors];

return (
    <fieldset>
        {updatedErrors.map((errorMessage, index) => {
            if (errorMessage === error_cred) {
                console.log("error_cred match", error_cred, errorMessage)
                return (
                    <button key={index} id={"match"}>{errorMessage} - click to clear</button>
                );
            } else {
                console.log("error_cred mismatch - this return doesn't re-render", error_cred, errorMessage)
                return (
                    <button key={index} id={"misMatch"} onClick={(e) => this.clearAlertsHandler(e)}>{errorMessage} - click to clear</button>
                );
            }
        })}
        <label className="text-uppercase">Username</label>
        <input
            name="email"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.email}
            placeholder="username"
            onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
        />
        <label className="text-uppercase">Password</label>
        <input
            className="mb20"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            value={this.state.password}
            placeholder="••••••••••"
            onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
        />
        <button name="submit" className="primary mb20" onClick={this.onLoginClick}>
            Login
        </button>
    </fieldset>
);
}
```

Comment: One question: where are error_cred, error_pass etc being set?

Comment: Also it looks like you’re manipulating your state directly with setState instead of the recommended callback function that takes previousState as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, React doesn't know that `error` array changed if you don't clear it.

I think you should do something like this:

```js
    clearAlertsHandler() {
       console.log("Clear alerts")
       this.setState({
          errors: [],
       });
       document.getElementById("misMatch").remove()
    }
```